# Derivative of Ricci tensor and Euler-Lagrange equations ambiguity

Tags: general-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, newtonian-gravity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus

I'm currently working in a problem about formulating a Lagrangian for Newton-Cartan theory and i'm currently proving if it works.

In order to do this i'm required to compute the derivative of the Lagrangian w.r.t x

$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} $

As it appears in the first term of the Euler-Lagrange equation

$ \frac{\partial L}{\partial x} - \partial_\mu \left( \frac{\partial L}{\partial (\partial_\mu x)} \right) = 0 $

But since $L$ depends on the Ricci tensor $ R_{00} $ this yields many terms with a factor of

$ \frac{\partial R_{00}}{\partial x}$

The problem is i don't know how to interpretate this derivative.
Is it a derivative w.r.t x as it is?
If that's the case them we would have

$\frac{\partial R_{00}}{\partial x} =0$

Since the ricci tensor doesn't depend on the coordinates.

But it could also be the partial derivative in an arbitrary direction i

$ \frac{\partial R_{00}}{\partial x^i} = \partial_i R_{00} $

Which would yield a long and tedious calculation which i don't wanna do in vain.

How am i supposed to interpretate this derivative?! Which of these two is actually the answer?

Edit: if the second case were true ¿which woueld be some physical/geometrical interpretation/visualization of the derivatives of the Ricci tensor?